# How to create a calendar image in memory to add to PDF?

Tags: java, image, pdf, calendar, itext

I have a requirement to add a calendar image to a PDF that I'm creating in a java application. The PDF is being created using iText, that's not an issue. I just don't know how to go about dynamically creating a calendar image? The calendar would have to accurately display the full month. I attached a sample of what it should look like given month of December 2015
[image: Cal 12/2015]

I'm thinking that if I can't get this resolved, to manually create these images for the next 36 months and then continuously do that. Obviously that's a last resort

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/graphics/graphics2d-examples) will help and you should probably have a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) as well

Comment: Does your requirement explicitly specify that it must be a rasterized image? Does your requirement take into account that there will be visual degradation when zooming in? (as noted by Bruno in his answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How strange, you post a requirement asking for an example that is completely developed in the official documentation.

In [chapter 4](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-4) of "iText in Action - Second Edition", I write about [tables](http://developers.itextpdf.com/tags/tables) and in the [PdfCalendar](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-4#196-pdfcalendar.java) example, I use a `PdfPTable` to create a calendar:

```
// create a table with 7 columns
table = new PdfPTable(7);
table.setTotalWidth(504);
// add the name of the month
table.getDefaultCell().setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
table.addCell(getMonthCell(calendar, locale));
int daysInMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int day = 1;
int position = 2;
// add empty cells
while (position != calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
    position = (position % 7) + 1;
    table.addCell("");
}
// add cells for each day
while (day <= daysInMonth) {
    calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day++);
    table.addCell(getDayCell(calendar, locale));
}
// complete the table
table.completeRow();
```

These are the helper methods that are used:

```
/**
 * Creates a PdfPCell with the name of the month
 * @param calendar a date
 * @param locale a locale
 * @return a PdfPCell with rowspan 7, containing the name of the month
 */
public PdfPCell getMonthCell(Calendar calendar, Locale locale) {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.setColspan(7);
    cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
    cell.setUseDescender(true);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(String.format(locale, "%1$tB %1$tY", calendar), bold);
    p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    cell.addElement(p);
    return cell;
}

/**
 * Creates a PdfPCell for a specific day
 * @param calendar a date
 * @param locale a locale
 * @return a PdfPCell
 */
public PdfPCell getDayCell(Calendar calendar, Locale locale) {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.setPadding(3);
    // set the background color, based on the type of day
    if (isSunday(calendar))
        cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
    else if (isSpecialDay(calendar))
        cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
    else
        cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
    // set the content in the language of the locale
    Chunk chunk = new Chunk(String.format(locale, "%1$ta", calendar), small);
    chunk.setTextRise(8);
    // a paragraph with the day
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(chunk);
    // a separator
    p.add(new Chunk(new VerticalPositionMark()));
    // and the number of the day
    p.add(new Chunk(String.format(locale, "%1$te", calendar), normal));
    cell.addElement(p);
    return cell;
}

/**
 * Returns true for Sundays.
 * @param calendar a date
 * @return true for Sundays
 */
public boolean isSunday(Calendar calendar) {
    if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Returns true if the date was found in a list with special days (holidays).
 * @param calendar a date
 * @return true for holidays
 */
public boolean isSpecialDay(Calendar calendar) {
    if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY)
        return true;
    if (specialDays.containsKey(String.format("%1$tm%1$td", calendar)))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Note that the `isSpecialDay()` method requires a `specialDays` object that contains a list of special days such as Ascension Day, Christmas, etc...

In [chapter 5](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-5) of the same book, I describe how to use events to change the way the table is rendered (rounded corners, special colors,...). This example is also named [PdfCalendar](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-5#232-pdfcalendar.java).

Incidentally, these two chapters are the first hits when you search the official web site for the key word [Calendar](http://itextpdf.com/search/node/Calendar). How come you didn't find these examples?

Also: why are you asking for an image? You want to use these calendar tables in a PDF, so why would you create a raster image? Raster images look really bad when you zoom in. Creating a table as described in my book, will result in a high-quality PDF.